# catkin_make not working in indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just upgraded to ubuntu 14.4 and did sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full. I used to use hydo on 13.04 so was familiar with catkin. However when I tried to catkin_make my packages, I was told catkin_make: command not found. I have checked ros-indigo-catkin is installed.

Are we suppose to use some of the hydro packages to "bridge the gap" for now? I'm asking this also because ROS-industrial is not yet available in indigo.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187621/catkin_make-not-working-in-indigo/) by [jess](https://answers.ros.org/users/19834/jess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you've sourced the ros Indigo setup file in your shell? Try `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`

On my Ubuntu 14.04 machine with Indigo, catkin_make is part of the ros-indigo-catkin package, and is located in /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jess](https://answers.ros.org/users/19834/jess/) on 2014-07-24**:
Thanks. For some reason my .bashrc was not being run when I log in like it used to. I've just made sure it does now. Btw, do you know if moveit and ros-industrial hydro can be run with indigo?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-24**:
I haven't used either on indigo. The build status page indicates that moveit is released: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=moveit and ros_industrial is not. Indigo is pretty similar to Hydro, so you may be able to compile the hydro version of ros_industrial from source on Indigo.